# Notifications are not showing on some devices when App is not in foreground

Tags: android, notifications

on some devices (seems to be api level independend, in this case Samsung S5 and Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 8" with Stock ROMs) the notifications are only shown when app is in foreground but not when it is in background.

I am sure that the service is running because I can see that in the android settings and it also works on other devices without problems.

```
public void generateProgressNotification(String title, String message) {
    long[] vibrate = new long[]{300};

    Intent intent = new Intent(mApplicationContext, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(NotificationHelper.START_SHOW_PROGRESS, true);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mApplicationContext, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mApplicationContext)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setVibrate(vibrate)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setLights(mApplicationContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary), 200, 200)
            .setContentText(message);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mApplicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(PROGRESS_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Has anyone an idea why the notifications does not work on all devices?

Best regards,
Moritz

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of android devices. The notification is only pushed if the user using the application. If application is not running then notification will be pushed on next run. I also had the same problem and then I searched for the issue and even used wakeful broadcast receiver but the problem was not solved.

Comment: In my case the application runs, but in the background.
I stop the service within the onDestroy method of my MainActivity which only should be executed when the process gets destroyed.
did you finally solve your issue?

Comment: I had this problem only with android 4.3. I tried same thing on android 2.3 there its working fine and notification pushed automatically even when application not running.

Comment: I used wakefull broadcast reciever and pushed notifications from gcm.

Comment: And i think you are manually putting notifications with your own code. right.?

Comment: That is right, I am running a background service that generates the notification with the code about. It is not related to any kind of receiver.